# How can I select the top 1 column value into a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is my table definition where I store the installation information:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InstallInfo](
  [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [Module] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Version] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [InstallDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_InstallInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  ([ID] ASC)
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What I want to do is get the top 1 row (install version) for a module, based on the latest date:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InstallInfo_GetLatest] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Module int, 
@Version nvarchar(50) out
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

set @Version = ''

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT TOP 1 @Version=[Version]
from InstallInfo
where [Module] = @Module
order by InstallDate

END
```

However, when I run the stored proc, I get this error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure InstallInfo_GetLatest, Line 0
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
```

Here is how I am executing the stored proc:

```
declare @Module int
set @Module = 1
declare @versionOut nvarchar(50)
exec InstallInfo_GetLatest Module, @versionOut output
select @versionOut as 'v OUT'
```

FOUND IT: Forgot the @ sign

```
exec InstallInfo_GetLatest @Module, @versionOut output
```

Thanks everybody !

Comment: how are you executing your sp?

Comment: You are probably calling the stored procedure with the wrong arguments.

Comment: are you calling your sp using `Module` instead of `@Module`?, or is that a typo?

Comment: bingo... can't see the forest for the trees :-(  sigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer after multiple comments and feedback:

```
  exec InstallInfo_GetLatest @Module, @versionOut output
```